# Car crash simulation

Tags: simulation, physics, finite-element-analysis

I want to ask you How can I make simulation of car crash ?

On the internet I found http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1459.asp . 
I think about using finite-element-method, but now I think it is too difficult for me :/
Do you know any good, not too accurate and not very hard-to-learn methods to simulate collision of two bodies ( two cubic cars ) with deforming?

My first idea was to made these cars with some number of rigid bodies, and connect them, but I don't know if it is good idea :/

Comment: You won't be able to avoid some math and physics here, sorry.

Comment: How many years do you think to spend on this?

Comment: years :D I want to make this in few weeks, I don't need very accurate method

Comment: @sim89: For what purpose are you trying to do it? A flash game? A 3D game? A 3D simulation for car development?

Comment: @thejh: I get this task from school, so I think it can't be task for years, beacouse I have 3 weeks to this, they told me that i can fake some behaviour, but it must look real

Comment: What must "look real", the motion of the cars, the damage, or both?

Answer (score 2):

Try reading [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) for starters. This and the references therein should point you in the right direction, more or less.